# AndroidHttpClient can not getEntity().getContent() after closed

Tags: android, httpclient, inputstream

```
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(USERAGENT);
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        return in;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

I put the this method in a Util class.
But when call getInputStream() in another class,I can't get the InputSteam because of AndroidHttpClient is closed.
if I don't close AndroidHttpClient, there appeared "leak found,AndroidHttpClient created and never closed".
How to get the content in this situation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this, for instance:

```
public InputStream getInputStream() {
    AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(USERAGENT);
    HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url);
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(new EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        client.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have enabled the INTERNET Permission on your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Include the above line in your Androidmanifest.xml