# User Agent on a url.getContent();

Tags: android, user-agent

I need to download one file from an url that i give from an xml after connect to other url. My problem is that i need the same user agent and ip to do both actions.

To obtain the xml, i use a PHP code that is hosted on my server and i send it the user agent of my app:

```
String ua=new WebView(ct).getSettings().getUserAgentString().trim();
ua = ua.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

Then i parse the xml with a generic RssParserSax that gives me all i need.

After, i try to download the file to a drawable var and i do this:

```
Drawable dd = ImageOperations(url);

private Drawable ImageOperations(String url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

private Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

But as i don't send the user agent, it does not give me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(useragent).

See an example here [AndroidHttpClient can not getEntity().getContent() after closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393426/androidhttpclient-can-not-getentity-getcontent-after-closed)

Answer (score 2):

Finally i did this to resolve:

```
Bitmap bmImg;

try {
    URL url = new URL(addres);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", ua);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.connect();
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

    bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imagen.setImageBitmap(bmImg);
    imagen.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```